# NodeJS - Updating object on request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following object:

```
 var user = {

        firstName: req.body.first_name,
        lastName:  req.body.last_name,
        email:     req.body.email,
        password: "",
        id:         "", 
    };
```

Now what I'm trying to do is post a request to the API and if the user is successfully saved in the database, it will return a user id as well as a password (Which can then be emailed to the person)..

```
request.post({

       url: process.env.API_SIGNEDIN_ENDPOINT + "users/store",
       form: user,
       headers: {
         Authorization: "Bearer " + req.session.authorization
       }

    }, function(error, response, body) {

       // Check the response
       var theResponse = JSON.parse(response.body);

       if(theResponse.code == 400)
       {
          var error = [
            {param: "email", msg: "This email address has already been taken!", value: ""}
          ];

          res.render("create", {
              errors: error,
          });
       }else{

         var theUser = JSON.parse(body);
         user.password = theUser.password;
         user.id       = theUser.id;
       }
    });
```

This is working fine, however, whenever I try to output `user` it's not updating the `user` object outside of this post. The user object is fine and it's working, the issue seems to be from when I try and access the user from this result callback. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Let's say I have "address1" (This is the persons main address) and I have "address2" (This is the persons second address).. The person might only have 1 address and therefore I only need to save one address. However using the logic that place everything in the `.then()` means I cannot do this because the user might not have 2 addresses but I still need to access the main address, for example:

```
mainAddress.save().then(function(addressData) {

              var theAddressLicenceTick = req.body.address_licence;

              if(theAddressLicenceTick)
              { 
                  var subAddress = models.addresses.build({ 
                      address_1:    "asasfasf", 
                      city:         "asfafsaf", 
                      postcode:     "asfasf", 
                      created_at:   new Date(), 
                      updated_at:   new Date(); 
                  }); 

                  subAddress.save().then(function(subAddress) {

                      // continue integration 
                      // would I have to do the functionality again?

                  }); 

              }else{
                  // The user only has one address 

              }
         });
```

Essentially, I have a `customer` table which can have multiple `addresses` through a link table. But I believe that there is an easier way instead of writing all of this code?

Comment: there is a typo in `user.passwird = theUser.password;`. shouldn't it be `password`, not `passwird`?

Comment: @Neutrosider Sorry. Fixed this now, this does not solve the problem, though

Comment: @Subburaj - I want to update the `user` object with the password and id returned from the API.. The issue is if I print the `user` outside of this request then it will say that the values are not there even though I am setting them

Comment: @Subburaj Is there a work around to this? Ideally, I would like to update the object so then I can use it later on..

Comment: DO the logic in the callback , what u r trying to do after the request call...If u post the code what u r doing after request, so that i can have an idea of what u r doing???

Comment: @Subburaj - Thanks, I have updated my question